# how to call external async await function in testcafe

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have `helper.js` which has a function as

```
async function getLink() {
  try {
    const message = await authorize(content);
    const link = message.match(/href=\"(.*?)\"/i);
    return link[1];
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log('Error loading:',+error);
    throw(error);
  }
}
module.exports.getLink = getLink;
```

I want to use this function inside the testcafe script after the test is executed

In test.spec.js

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
let link = '';
fixture My fixture
.page `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;

 test('test1', async t => {

// do something with clientWidth
});
test('test2', async t => {
  // use the getLink function here from the helper.js to get the string value
  mailer.getLink().then(res=>{
    link = res;
  })
  t.navigateTo(link)
});
```

How to solve this issue?

I tried using clientFunction but getting error as `_ref is not defined` the code is as follows

```
const validationLink = ClientFunction(() => {
  return getLink();
}, { dependencies: { getLink } });
let link = await validationLink();
```

Comment: Instead of `mailer.getLink().then(res=>{link = res;})`, do `link = await mailer.getLink();`

Comment: await didn't work :(

Answer (score 5):

If the `getLink` method must read something in the DOM (that is outside the scope of the `Selector`) or must compute something special within the browser, you have to create a `clientFunction` like the following (with all code (no imported code) inside the clientFunction):

```
const getLink = ClientFunction((selector) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
        const element = selector();
        // check, in developper tools, what are the available properties in element
        console.log("element:", element);
        // code omitted for brevity that reads data from element and does special computation from it
        // build the result to be returned
        const result = 'the computed link';
        resolve(result);
    });
});

test('test2', async t => {
  const linkSelector = Selector('css selector');
  const link = await getLink(inputSelector);
  await t.navigateTo(link);
});
```

If the `getLink` method does not need to read something special from the DOM, then there is no need to create a `clientFunction`. You just need to create a helper method and import it (as suggested by @AlexSkorkin):

```
test('test2', async t => {
  const link = await mailer.getLink();
  await t.navigateTo(link)
});
```

Notice that t.navigate() must be awaited and mailer.getLink().

Comment: as per your suggestion, if i try the same i'm getting error as 

ReferenceError: getLocation is not defined

Comment: If would be nice if you could provide the final code of the ClientFunction.Maybe you call an imported module, in a ClientFunction which could be the cause of the error

Comment: I'm not using clientFunction as you said I'm not using the DOM-related stuff.

instead using the second one const link = await mailer.getLink();
  await t.navigateTo(link)

Comment: In this case, you could debug your code within Visual Studio Code by using the TestCafe extension 'TestCafe Test Runner'. Install this extension, put a breakpoint inside the getLink function then right-click on the fixture file and select 'TestCafe: run tests in Chrome' and you will automatically step in debug mode when the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Since async/await function won't work inside clientFunction As a workaround, I moved the test into a separate file and moved the getLink() function outside the test

if you want to run this two files one after other add the scripts in package.json as "testcafe chrome file1.js && testcafe chrome file2.js"

Any direct answers are welcomed